# Pass a password & username without prompting in Powershell to open an application

Tags: windows, powershell, notepad

I'm working on a script (.ps1) to open Microsoft Dynamics Nav with a specific user credential. The last error I received was "Directory name is invalid," even though I copied & pasted it from file explorer. I need it to where it launches the application with the given credentials - without prompting for the password & username.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Pre-saved credentials 

$Username = "domain\x"

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "x" -AsPlainText -Force

$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($Username,$Password) 

#Open the application with the inputted credentials 

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80\RoleTailored Client\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe" -Credential $Cred
```

I initially managed to do it without typing in the username but a popup window asks for the password; however, I need it to where it doesn't prompt\pop up anything, which is what my code indicates but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the arguments ($username, $password) for the new credential.

Comment: @DougMaurer, that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post.

Comment: @DougMaurer, It isn't wrong, just unnecessary in this case; also, there are subtle differences that don't surface here: without `(...)`, the array elements are parsed in _argument_ mode; with `(...)`, they're parsed in _expression_ mode; e.g. `Write-Output foo, bar` vs. `Write-Output ('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: @mklement0 The password & username are correct; however, the error comes from the last line. One approach I tried was using the password & username as an argument list when using '-Credential' but failed.

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: As pointed out by @mklement0, the method employed by the OP should NOT generate a prompt.
> Also, while functional, the "solution" presented here prompts the user for a password, thus defeating the OP's original intent of using pre-saved credentials.

Try using **Read-Host**

This will read the input from console. *Without opening a new window.*

Using the `-AsSecureString` parameter will display the input as asterisks and convert the string into a SecureString object, that can then be used to create the credentials that will be sent to the application.

Like this example:

`$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Insert your password: " -AsSecureString`

Comment: Note that the OP is using `ConvertTo-SecureString "x" -AsPlainText -Force` to obtain a `[securestring]` instance and uses that to construct a `[pscredential]` instance - thus, there's no need to prompt for a password. Thus, the real question is why a prompt is presented nonetheless.

Comment: Indeed! A bad case of "read it too fast" by my part, my apologies! And thank you for poiting out.